# Getting dates for the nearest n day of week

Tags: ruby, date

I try to implement method, that return collection of dates for the nearest n day of week e.g. Monday.

My method:

```
  def date_of_next(day, weeks)
    date = Date.parse(day)
    if date > Date.today
      delta = 0
      date + delta
    else
      (0..weeks.to_i).each do |i|
        delta = 7 * i
        date + delta
      end
    end
  end
```

I don't have any idea to properly repair this method. Could you help me?
Thanks in advance.

My prediction of return:

Code of select:

```
= f.select :date_of_training, label: "Data",
  collection: @trainer.work_schedules.map{ |tw| [tw.next_n_days(4, "Monday"), tw.id]},
  prompt: "Wybierz datę"
```

Result:

```
2016-05-16
2016-05-16
2016-05-30
2016-06-06
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the method is supposed to return. Could your show the expected output when calling the method with different argument values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naïve implementation:

```
def next_n_days(amount, day_of_week)
  (Date.today...Date.today+7*amount).select do |d|
    d.wday == day_of_week
  end
end

#     three ⇓  ⇓ Fridays
next_n_days 3, 5
#⇒ [
#   [0] #<Date: 2016-05-13 ((2457522j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
#   [1] #<Date: 2016-05-20 ((2457529j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
#   [2] #<Date: 2016-05-27 ((2457536j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
# ]
```

More accurate implementation:

```
def next_n_days(amount, day_of_week)
  nearest = (Date.today...Date.today+7).detect { |d| d.wday == day_of_week }
  nearest.step(nearest+7*amount-1, 7).to_a
end
```

Comment: something is wrong, because variable nearest is nil, i checked amount and day_of_week has value.

Comment: What value has `day_of_week`? It is supposed to conform `wday` format (`0` for Sunday, `1` for Monday etc.) **OK**, with your update I see you want to pass names like `"Monday"`. It was not specified in the original question as it was posted, so I leave this as an exercise to you.